# Characterisations of closed embeddings in $Top_1$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $Top_1$ be the category of topological spaces which are $T_1.$

I am curious as to whether there is a **categorical** definition of what a closed embedding is in this environment. With a categorical definition, I mean something along the lines that in the category $Top_2$ , consisting of topological spaces which are $T_2,$ the closed embeddings are precisely the extremal monomorphisms.

In $Top$ (and $Top_1$) the extremal monomorphisms are precisely the embeddings. In $Top$ we can use the Sierpinski space to single out the ones with closed image, but this is not possible in $Top_1$ since the Sierpinski object is not $T_1.$

Any comments or thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: I think all extremal monomorphisms are closed embeddings in Hausdorff spaces. If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is an extremal mono ,consider $Z = \overline{f(X)}$ (the closure of the images) and let $g:X \rightarrow Z$ be the obvious map and $i: Z \rightarrow Y$ the inclusion. $g$ is an epi in the category of Hausdorff spaces,since it has dense image, so is an iso since f is supposed to be extremal. In the category of Hausdorff spaces, closed embeddings are regular monomorphisms, and since every regular monomorphism is extremal, the claim should follow.

Answer (score 9):

As partial motivation, let me start with the observation that in $\mathrm{Set}$, if $i: A \to B$ is a monomorphism, then $i$ is retrieved as the pullback of the monomorphism $\ast \cong A/A \hookrightarrow B/A$ along the canonical map $q: B \to B/A$ (where $B/A$ is the pushout or cofiber product of $i$ and the unique map $A \to 1$). This is one of the exactness properties singled out by Freyd in a categories-list [discussion](http://www.mta.ca/~cat-dist/catlist/1999/atcat) that are common to pretoposes and abelian categories. The square

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \to & 1 \\
i \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
B & \stackrel{q}{\to} & B/A
\end{array}$$

which is simultaneously a pushout and pullback is sometimes called, affectionately, a "dolittle square" (after the pushmi-pullyu in the Doctor Dolittle story). So not knowing quite what to call such monomorphisms in general, I'll call it a dolittle monomorphism.

In other words, a monomorphism $i$ in a category with finite limits and pushouts will be called *dolittle* if it is the pullback of the inclusion $1 \to B/A$ in the pushout square above. Then in $\mathrm{Top}_1$, closed embeddings $i: A \to B$ are precisely dolittle monomorphisms. (Notice that the pushout construction $B/A$ in $\mathrm{Top}_1$ is constructed as the pushout $B/\bar{A}$ in $\mathrm{Top}$.)

Comment: This is very nice! Do you know if there is a similar characterization for $T_0$-spaces? Maybe I should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: There is a nasty trick that lets us recognise the Sierpiński space in $\mathbf{Top}$ as an abstract category. Once we have that, we can identify the closed embeddings. See [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20822327#20822327).